# What is the result of this regex?

Tags: regex

Assume I have this pattern that I wish to find `[a][a]`
Assume that the text on which I will test my pattern-finder is this: `[a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a]`

My pattern-finder will return these results for first iteration:

```
[a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a]
[a][a]
```

For second iteration:

```
[a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a]
   [a][a]
```

In other words the pattern "skips" one item to the right.

I tested my regex on some regex sites and what I saw is that they skip forward at the length of the pattern - which visually would look like this:

First iteration:

```
[a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a]
[a][a]
```

Second iteration:

```
[a][a][a][a][a][a][a][a]
      [a][a]
```

Who is right? Me or the websites? And why?

Comment: the second is right because you can't have overlapped results. If you want to have overlapped results, you need to put your pattern in a capture group inside a lookahead.

Comment: Usually regex findall ignores overlaps, as @CasimiretHippolyte suggests. This is possibly for performance reasons. See python's `re.findall`.

Comment: @simonzack: no, it isn't for performance reasons, it is simply the way the regex engine walks: once a position is reached in the string, it continues from left to right.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte "That's just how it works" is a circular argument. You might as well say "The world is flat because it is". It is trivial to modify the regex matching engine to start from the next position.

Comment: @simonzack no need to modify the engine. Depending on your lib you can manually control iteration, like specifying the start offset yourself. This would let you trivially get overlapping matches.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I'm aware of this, but I was refuting Casimir's argument.

Comment: To be clear, to obtain overlapped results, you can use `(?=(\[a\]\[a\]))`

Comment: @simonzack: it isn't a circular argument, it is a left to right argument.

Comment: I think @CasimiretHippolyte should summarize this little conversation in an answer, and also I think op used `[a]` accidentally not knowing (or ignoring) the fact that `[`/`]` are special in standard regex implementations, but not in a university math lectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who is right? Me or the websites?

Websites

> why?

Because `\[a\]\[a\]` regex would match the first two `[a][a]` during the first iteration. For the second iteration, it won't do an overlapping match that is the second `[a]` was already matched during the first iteration, so third and fourth `[a]` got matched instead of two and three. Use lookaheads, in-order to do an overlapping captures.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on pattern.

```
(\[a\])(?=(\[a\])|$)
```

Try this.This pattern will make your answer correct.Look at the matches on the right side.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/7

```
(\[a\])(\[a\])
```

This will make websites correct.See the matches at the right side.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/8